# Difference in meaning of 관객 and 청중

Tags: difference

What is the difference between 관객 and 청중.  Do both mean 'public'? How might we use both words in context?

Comment: 이 경우 두 단어의 한자의 의미를 알면 어떤 차이가 있는지 쉽게 알 수 있으며 문맥애 알맞게 쓸 수 있습니다.

Answer (score 2):

`관객` means "spectator" and `청중` means "audience". `관객` indicates people watching something visual, while `청중` means people listening to something auditory. But I think you don't have to distinguish them because visual contents and sounds are used simultaneously nowadays.

`관` in `관객(觀客)` means "see", and `청` in `청중(聽衆)` means "listen to".